# A problem of Tangent on Ellipse.

Tags: conic-sections

I have a question that requires me to find out the minimum value (length) of a segment of a tangent to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ intercepted by the coordinate axes.
This is the diagram,
[image: Tangent on Ellipse]

This is what I have done,

We know that, equation of tangent to ellipse in parametric form is,
 $$\frac{x\cos\theta}{a}+\frac{y\sin\theta}{b}=1$$

So,
 $$\frac{x}{a\sec\theta}+\frac{y}{b\csc\theta}=1$$

So, segment of tangent between coordinate axes = $\sqrt{a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\csc^2\theta}$

Therefore we need to find the minimum value of $\sqrt{a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\csc^2\theta}$.
How do I do that?

Comment: Take the derivative and set it $ = 0 $

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170736/more-than-one-minimum-value

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\csc^2\theta= a^2(1+\tan^2\theta)+b^2(1+\cot^2\theta)$$
$$=a^2+b^2+ (a\tan\theta-b\cot\theta)^2+2ab\ge a^2+b^2+2ab$$

The equality i.e., the minimum length occurs if $a\tan\theta-b\cot\theta=0\iff \tan^2\theta=\frac ba$