# Minimizing $9 \sec^2{x} + 16 \csc^2{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Find the minimum value of $$9 \sec^2{x} + 16 \csc^2{x}$$
My turn :
Using AM-GM
$$9\sec^2{x} + 16\csc^2{x} \geq 2 \sqrt{144 \sec^2{x} \csc^2{x}}$$ 
$$9 \sec^2{x} + 16\csc^2{x} \geq 24 \sec{x} \csc{x} $$
But the equality sign holds iff
$$9 \sec^2{x} = 16\csc^2{x}$$
Then $$ \tan{x} = \frac{4}{3}$$
Then the minimum value is $$24 \times \frac{5}{4} \times \frac{5}{3} = 50$$
Is there any mistake with the solution ?

Comment: It is $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $$a,b\geq 0$$

Comment: I have miss-typed it but the question holds @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: The solution is wrong. Using your idea, the minimum value of $x^2+1$ with $x> 0$ is $2$, which is wrong.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170736/more-than-one-minimum-value

Comment: Why is it wrong ? Is not this the definition of AM-GM inequality ? @mathlove

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed: By AM-GM inequality, we get $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$. This is true, and if $2\sqrt{ab}$ is a **constant**, then the minimum value of $a+b$ is attained only when $a=b$. However, if $2\sqrt{ab}$ is not a constant, then $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$ does not say anything about the minimum value of $a+b$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake in the following.

You proved that $$\frac{9}{\cos^2x}+\frac{16}{\sin^2x}\geq\frac{24}{|\sin{x}\cos{x}|}=\frac{48}{|\sin2x|},$$
but you did not find a minimal value.

After your first step we see that $$\frac{48}{|\sin2x|}\geq48,$$ but it does not give a minimal value because the value $48$ does not occur.

One of right solutions is the following.

By C-S
$$\frac{9}{\cos^2x}+\frac{16}{\sin^2x}=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)\left(\frac{9}{\cos^2x}+\frac{16}{\sin^2x}\right)\geq(3+4)^2=49.$$
The equality occurs for $(\cos{x},\sin{x})||\left(\frac{3}{\cos{x}},\frac{4}{\sin{x}}\right),$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 1):

By differentiating and setting to $0$ or plotting the graph, the minimum value is actually $49$, so there must be something wrong in your solution.

From $9 \sec^2 x = 16 \csc^2 x$ you cannot deduce $\tan x = \frac{4}{3}$. You have $\tan^2 x = \frac{16}{9}$, but $\tan x$ can either be $\frac{4}{3}$ or $-\frac{4}{3}$.

In addition, $24 \sec x \csc x$ is actually negative for some values of $x$, such as $x = 2$. Therefore you have not actually proven that $50$ is the minimum value, but rather that the function is always greater than some negative number.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Rozenberg has already given an answer using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Here's my answer using the AM-GM inequality.

Write $\sec^2 x = 1 + \tan^2 x$ and $\csc^2 x = 1 + \cot^2 x$. Then
$$9\sec^2 x + 16\csc^2 x = 9(1+\tan^2 x) + 16(1+ \cot^2 x) = 25 + 9\tan^2 x + \frac{16}{\tan^2 x}.$$
Then by AM-GM inequality
$$9\tan^2 x + \frac{16}{\tan ^2 x} \geq 2\sqrt{9\tan^2 x\cdot\frac{16}{\tan^2 x}}$$
$$=2\sqrt{9\cdot 16}=2\cdot3\cdot4 = 24.$$
Thus 
$$9\sec^2 x + 16\csc^2 x \geq 25+ 24=49.$$